# How to Add Basic Auth(Pre-emptive) to Web Service Client genrated with Web Platform Tools (WTP0 in Eclipse

Tags: web-services

I have a web service that I want to consume that requires a username and password. It does not prompt you for the u/p. In SOAPUI 4.5 it is very easy to go to the Auth tab for the web service , choose auth type: premeptive, add the username and password and run the service. I have generated a web service client for this service using Eclipse WTP but I cannot figure out what code to add and where in order to provide this same u/p that works in Soapui. I am fairly new so be specific please (does the code go in the servicebindingstub, serviceporttype, serviceporttypeproxy, and what method ? _init, etc., include imports pls. The wtp client works but returns a error code stating that the username and password are missing. If there is a way to externalize this in the descriptor that would be great also.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by adding Username and Password lines (last two below) to the Call for each method in the Stub file.

```
call.setUseSOAPAction(true);
        _call.setSOAPActionURI("urn:webservicesapi#getAllVirtualServerConnStats");
        _call.setEncodingStyle(null);
        _call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.client.Call.SEND_TYPE_ATTR, Boolean.FALSE);
        _call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.PROP_DOMULTIREFS, Boolean.FALSE);
        _call.setSOAPVersion(or`enter code here`g.apache.axis.soap.SOAPConstants.SOAP11_CONSTANTS);
        _call.setOperationName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("", "getAllVirtualServerConnStats"));
        _call.setProperty (Call.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "wstest");  //added this
        _call.setProperty (Call.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "WsTest");  // added this

        setRequestHeaders(_call);
```